# PHP HTML ASCII encode without modify HTML tags

Tags: php, html, ascii, encode

Im trying to make a simple script to prevent robots to read the webpage.

Im currently using this code:

```
<?php echo "&#".ord("f").";"; ?>
```

that output:

```
&#102;
```

and in your brownser you see:

> f

it's a simple script using HTML ASCII encode: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_ascii.asp (for more information).

But i want to encode a such string without modify the HTML code (this is an example, not the real string):

```
<p>i<a href="#">s</a>o</p>
```

I want to output:

```
<p>&#105;<a href="#">&#115;</a>&#111;</p>
```

and see in brownser:

> iso

is this possible? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks you.

Comment: No robot that uses an HTML parser would be at all confused by this.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might help you

```
<p><?php echo html_entity_decode(htmlentities("&#".ord("i").";")); ?><a href="#">
<?php echo html_entity_decode(htmlentities("&#".ord("s").";")); ?></a>
<?php echo html_entity_decode(htmlentities("&#".ord("f").";")); ?></p>
```

for more information , refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php and this

http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: Im sorry, I didn't expressed correctly my problem. Question is updated.

Comment: you can see the source code and output at the browser , it is there as you required

Comment: this will out your desired output

Comment: "this is an example, not the real string", I want to do it dinamically.

Comment: for every alphabet run that function using array , convert it and then use it , atleast you got the base line  of code